# Window.print Prints Incorrect Content in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm having trouble getting Google Chrome to print the correct content when I change the content of a modal page with JavaScript. This is my code:

**Javascript:**

```
function printCoupon(couponID)
{
  var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
  var printable = document.getElementById(couponID);
  var printContents = printable.innerHTML;

  document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

  window.print();

  document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <div id="coupon1"><p>Coupon 1 contents</p></div>
  <div><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="printCoupon('coupon1');return false;">Print Coupon</a></div>
  <div id="coupon2"><p>Coupon 2 contents</p></div>
  <div><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="printCoupon('coupon2');return false;">Print Coupon</a></div>
</body>
```

This works in IE8 and FF 3.6, but Chrome 16 prints the original content, not the printable content.

**UPDATE:** I just discovered another problem with this. In IE9, the parent page is printed along with the modal (the modal looks transparent), instead of just the modal.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found the answer to both my problems.  The solution was to split the script into three scripts (before, during and after print) and use setTimeout on the second two. It works perfectly, now.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the print-job hasn't been sended yet when you re-assign the original innerHTML.

I would prefer a css-solution:

CSS:

```
@media print{
body > div{display:none;}
.printable{display:block !important}
}
```

JS:

```
function printCoupon(couponID)
{
  if(window['printable'])
  {
    window['printable'].className='';
  }
   window['printable']=document.getElementById(couponID);
   window['printable'].className='printable';
  window.print();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately, there are a couple of problems with this. First, I need to replace everything in the body with the contents of the div. This just gives the div a new class name and leaves everything else behind. Second, now the print preview fails in Chrome.

Comment: Why do you need to replace everything?

Comment: So that only the selected coupon is printed. There are many coupons listed on the page.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? Only visible things will be printed and my solution hides everything else than the selected coupon (take a look at the print-review, you will not see the change in the browser-window, the CSS  only applies to printing). See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/2j7LT/

Comment: I see what you mean, but I think users would find that confusing in other browsers that don't get a print-preview. I'd rather have them see what they will be printing in all browsers.